# Can't call properies to access resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, picturebox

So I have a picture box. I want to change the picture in the box when its clicked. I want to call the image from the references of the program. Here is what I understand of the code to use:
Here is a cut up snippet of what I am trying to do:

```
namespace Control
{
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
         private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            pictureBox.Image=Properties.Resources.mypic;
         }
     }
}
```

The problem is, while using winforms C#, Visual Studio is not recognizing the "Properties" part of that code.
  I have tried  `this.Properties`, `Form1.Properties`, and `Control.Properties`.

I have also set the image properties in my resource list to embed as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
yourAppName.Properties.Resources.mypic;
```

- yourAppName being your application namespace.

Comment: I don't know why, but I tried that and it didn't work. So I gave up and asked here. Now its working.. I must have been messing something up. But it works now. Just like you said. Perfect

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't know where the Properties class lives.

In the IDE:

1. Right-click on `Properties`
2. Select 'Resolve'

This is easier (to me) than remembering what namespace different classes live in.